# Rails 3.1: Model Constant in initializer causes warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warnings, constants, ruby-on-rails-3.1, initializer

I have monkey patched the Tag class of the ActsAsTaggableOn plugin in an an initializer. All works fine, however I get a warning for a constant I added to Tag:

config/initializers/acts_as_taggable_on_extensions.rb:

```
 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

   ... some stuff ...

   TAG_TYPES = [:a, :b, :c]

   ... some more stuff ....

 end
```

The warning is: config/initializers/acts_as_taggable_on_extensions.rb:136: warning: already initialized constant TAG_TYPES

How can I get rid of this warning?

I'm on ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1 rc4.

Comment: The newest release of Rails 3.1 is rc5, you should consider to update the prereleases as soon as an update is available.

Comment: In my opinion, your file is getting loaded more than once. Can you check if that's the case?

Comment: @Aurril: I had trouble with the asset pipeline in rc5, I rolled back to rc4.

Comment: @Chirantan: Yes, that is what i suspect too, just not sure where and why.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TAG_TYPES ||= [:a, :b, :c]
```

Comment: That did the trick, thx ;-). Just wondering why it is loaded twice in the first place.

Comment: Ok, just check that the values you're expecting are those ones you specified here, and not others. In the latter case, the problem is not that the code has been evaluated twice, but that you are probably reassigning a pre-assigned const...

Comment: This constant is only assigned once. And it's values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own Tag Types by adding them to the TAG_TYPES array.

```
TAG_TYPES << :a << :b << :c
TAG_TYPES.uniq!
```